# Is there a tree control for Lightswitch?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

Is there a tree control for Lightswitch? I have a self referencing table I want to show in a tree format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael Washington has a blog on creating one yourself:

http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/53/Tree-Control-Hierarchical-Data-with-LightSwitch.aspx